# How pedantic is too pedantic?

Tags: discussion

In this question, [Can I select the nearest quest to my location in my Pip-Boy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250551/can-i-select-the-nearest-quest-to-my-location-in-my-pip-boy/250554#250554), I seem to have an issue with the accepted answer.

I am aware that my answer clearly doesn't give you a way to do what the question is asking, but I feel like it answers the question.

The accepted answer doesn't answer the question, but instead gives you a way of finding the closest objective out of all of your quests combined.

It is my experience with SE that it's based on a question -> answer system, not a "you can do it kind of like this" system, if there is no good way to accomplish what the question is asking.

I feel like the community seems to think I'm being too literal with my "answer only what the question asks" way of thinking.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing the accepted answer says is:

> There's no way to do precisely what you want

It is answering the question, and being helpful to boot. It's a great answer! Put yourself in the mindset of the question asker. They might ask a question that has no good answer, but the broader problem they're dealing with might have other solutions that you can help with.

If you can answer their question and be helpful you'll likely get more upvotes/accepts than you would otherwise, in my experience.

Comment: Note that the quoted line was added [after Chase and another user commented](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/250558/revisions).

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks, I didn't notice. Without that, it's still a good answer, and one that solved the asker's problem (hence they accepted it).

Comment: No problem. Just thought it worth pointing out that the 'pedantry' as Chase calls it actually helped to improve the answer, even if the OP was none too happy about the help :)

Comment: @Robotnik Ah thanks for pointing that out. I also did not notice that the question was even edited to include what fredley mentioned until just now. Perhaps that's why I have more of a problem with it than I do now.